# Are there any guidelines for having space between the form elements (fields)?

Tags: forms, design

Are there any guidelines for having space between the form elements (fields)?

Comment: Yes, have some.

Comment: Why complicate things for yourself. Pick something you think looks appropriate, or if you're unsure then have a look at the hundreds of examples there are of form layouts from notable websites.

Comment: Alright Thanks. Was facing some issue in handling spacing while designing a form for a application.

Answer (score 1):

> You know a layout has good spacing when:
>
> - Overall, the UI surface feels comfortable and doesn't feel cramped.
> - The space appears uniform and balanced.
> - Related elements are close together and unrelated elements are relatively far apart.
> - There is no dead space between controls that are meant to be together, such as toolbar buttons.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511279.aspx

Comment: Microsoft has its quirks, but if you have to reject them, reject them because they are faulty, not simply just because they are authored by Microsoft. These guidelines, however, are proficient and worth to follow.

Comment: Microsoft designed a touch OS and deployed it on a desktop. End of. :)

Comment: Microsoft has many failings. Internet Explorer being one the biggest ever, but please talk to the point relevant to the question/answer and subject matter.
Which of their suggestions exactly you are not finding good enough from the link I provided??

Comment: Nothing wrong with the link!

Answer (score 0):

I've read that the most commonly used space between the fields is the field height. You can use the space to develop some kind of pace in your form - **if you want your users to fill in the fields carefully and slowly, make the gaps bigger** and align the labels to the right. Of course these are just some general rules, so here comes the classic - DEPENDS OF THE PROJECT :)